# HTTP POST -> 400: Bad Request

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm learning how to make an API and for now the API works fine (with Postman). I'm now trying to make an application which uses it and I managed to make GET and DELETE request but I'm stuck at the POST and PUT ones.

Here what I tried for the POST:

```
url = "http://localhost:8000/musiques"

let titre = document.getElementById('formTitre').value;
let auteur = document.getElementById('formAuteur').value;
let genre = document.getElementById('formGenre').value;
let annee = document.getElementById('formAnnee').value;
let image = document.getElementById('formImage').value;

let jsonArr = [];

jsonArr.push({
    auteur: auteur,
    titre: titre,
    genre: genre,
    annee: annee,
    image: image
});
console.log(jsonArr);

let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", url);
req.send(jsonArr);
```

when I try it I have an error 400 bad request.

---

EDIT:
ok so now I have this:

```
let titre = document.getElementById('formTitre').value;
let auteur = document.getElementById('formAuteur').value;
let genre = document.getElementById('formGenre').value;
let annee = document.getElementById('formAnnee').value;
let image = document.getElementById('formImage').value;

let jsonArr = [];

console.log(titre);

jsonArr.push({
    auteur: auteur,
    titre: titre,
    genre: genre,
    annee: annee,
    image: image
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonArr));

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonArr),
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

which give me an error:

```
Success: {"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":
[{"message":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO api_musique
(auteur, genre, image, annee, titre) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params 
[null, null, null, null, null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint 
violation: 1048 Le champ 'auteur' can't be empty
```

which is much better now. Thanks a lot, I'm working on it.

Comment: any more info than that in the response from the remote server? Don't forget we have no idea what format of request it expects, what data values it considers valid, or what values you actually sent.

Comment: @ADyson i made some changes it's better with this error message indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(jsonArr) })
```

More about [usage here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which you can use to get information [about the response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Response_objects).

The reponse object will allow you to figure out why you are getting a `400`. Otherwise this might be an issue caused by your API.

Answer (score 2):

here is the correction

```
let titre = document.getElementById('formTitre').value;
let auteur = document.getElementById('formAuteur').value;
let genre = document.getElementById('formGenre').value;
let annee = document.getElementById('formAnnee').value;
let image = document.getElementById('formImage').value;

let jsonArr = {
    auteur: auteur,
    genre: genre,
    image: image,
    annee: parseInt(annee),
    titre: titre
};

console.log(titre);


console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonArr));

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonArr),
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

thanks a lot everyone